# Java library to assist in XSD creation?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

Is anyone aware of a library that makes the process of creating XSDs in Java a little easier than using something like a DocumentBuilder? Something like a helper or utility class.  I came across the org.eclipse.xsd maven jar but I'm having ClassNotFoundException issues when working with it in Eclipse and I'm not entirely sure it's meant to be used as a standalone kind of thing. This is a bit difficult to Google for as well since there are lot of search results around automatic generation/translation from Java to XSD and vice versa.

Essentially what I need to do is to programmatically create an XSD from a certain source of data -- not Java classes.

Comment: I know you have mentioned "create an XSD from a certain source of data -- not Java classes", but is there possibled get a representation of your data source as a java class?

Comment: @emecas Yes, but it's not a fully faithful representation of the data, at least not without some additional work, so I think it makes sense to go directly to the XSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache XMLSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/xmlschema20/) is `a lightweight Java object model that can be used to manipulate and generate XML schema representations. You can use it to read XML Schema (xsd) files into memory and analyze or modify them, or to create entirely new schemas from scratch.`

The fact that with this API one can create an XSD from scratch, it sounds as a starting point to achieve the ask; as to the fitness, it depends on what that "certain source of data" is.

Comment: Looks promising. Upvoted. Give me a few days and if it pans out, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The link from the parent is now 404, but it appears that is now available on: https://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/

Comment: After more careful inspection, the actual link should be https://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/ now (the url above links to the old 1.x) releases.